# Edge not removing localStorage entries

Tags: javascript, local-storage, microsoft-edge

I have been unable to remove localStorage entries from Edge across page loads. I tried with js first with `localStorage.removeItem('foo')` and then removed them manually in dev tools. The row gets removed but comes back on page reload. As if the changes to localStorage are not being saved. This only happens in Edge, Chrome works fine. Any ideas?

Edit: Not a typo in real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other part of another `window` `DOMContentLoaded` was settings localstorage on page load. D'oh moment right there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you misspelt "localStorage". Try this:

```
localStorage.removeItem("foo");
```

Comment: Ah no, I just typed it here. It's not a typo in the browser. The same code works in chrome. So it's edge related.

Comment: I see, I thought it was a simple fix :P

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a typo: `localSotrage`. localStorage does: https://jsfiddle.net/azjbt36m/1/

Comment: Ah no, I just typed it here. It's not a typo in the browser. The same code works in chrome. So it's edge related.

Comment: My example works in Edge so it must be in (an other part of) your code

Comment: Yeah it works for me as well but does it stay deleted across page loads?

Comment: Also there is no other part of my code that can be relevant because it's not my code that's showing the behavior. Did you read the question. It doesn't get deleted even from dev tools. Has nothing to do with my code.

Comment: "Does it stay deleted across page loads" - reload the fiddle. I guess there's a part in your code that sets the localStorage after you removed it

Comment: No, I think I am not able to get the point across. My code doesn't even run. I just open the dev tools and remove the item. On reload it's back there. Plus if my code was doing something fishy, it would also do the same thing on chrome or firefox. The code works fine on others.